# What is the name of this inequality?

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be a collection of nonnegative random variables. Then
$$
\max_i X_i \le \epsilon/2 + \sum_i X_i \mathbb{1}_{\{X_i > \epsilon/2\}}.
$$
Does this inequality have a name? What is it?

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with probability theory. It is true when  $X_n$'s are real numbers, hence also for random variables. It has no name because it doesn't deserve one!.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy just because it's true in two different situations doesn't mean it doesn't have anything to do with one of those situations. Moreover, easily-verified does not mean undeserving of a name--I'm sure you can think of a few examples yourself. Finally, it has already been suggested that this inequality doesn't have a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this has a name. But it is a combination of some simple [but also unnamed] results.

Under the event $\max_i X_i \le \epsilon / 2$, then the inequality holds automatically.

So we may assume we are in the event $\max_i X_i > \epsilon / 2$.
We then have
$\max_i X_i \le \sum_i X_i \mathbb{1}_{X_i > \epsilon / 2}$ because the right-hand side equals $\max_i X_i$ plus some other nonegative addends.

Comment: No I get the proof, I'm just wondering if it has a name. I'll wait a little bit and just in case nobody else steps forward with one, I'll accept the previous part as an answer. Thanks.